# Java Project Analysis with Infer that Contains .jj Files

Tags: maven, javacc, facebook-infer

I have a Java project with a single .jj file that should be compiled using JavaCC.
The relevant plugin in the `pom.xml` file is as follows:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <id>javacc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>javacc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/apache/jute/compiler/generated/</sourceDirectory>
              <includes>
                <include>rcc.jj</include>
              </includes>
              <lookAhead>2</lookAhead>
              <isStatic>false</isStatic>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

While this plugin does its job beautifully with the command `mvn clean generate-sources`, it just is not called with the command `infer capture -- mvn clean generate-sources`.
My guess is that this plugin is incompatible with Facebook Infer, as I could not find any other points of failure; the entire project builds successfully without Infer, after all.

Please, if either there be another point of failure, let me know.
If you would like more information, I'd be happy to provide them.